# Draggable Bug : div may go out of place when I hold one of the div and drag, but back to normal when I drop?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, jquery-ui-draggable

I created 6 div and manage to place them inside a box, when I drag of the div, rest of my divs will seem to move to other place, even went out of the box?

however when I drop the div, everything went back to its place?

can anyone explain why it happen?

This is my code

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <title>Javascript Create Div Element Dynamically</title>

    <style type="text/css">
.ex
{
width:200px;
position: relative;
background-color :#CCC;
height:150px;
padding:10px;
margin:5px;
left-margin:0px;
float :left;
}
#newdiv
{
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
 border:1px solid #000;     
}
.border
{
 border:1px solid #000; 
}

    </style>
<script>

image.cc=1;
function changeimage(image)
{
if (image.cc==0) 
  {
  image.cc=1;
  $(image).attr('src', 'images/white_contact.png');
  }
else if (image.cc==1)
  {
  image.cc=2;
  $(image).attr('src', 'images/yellow_contact.png');
  }
  else if (image.cc==2)
  {
  image.cc=3;
    $(image).attr('src', 'images/green_contact.png');
  }
    else
  {
  image.cc=0;
    $(image).attr('src', 'images/red_contact.png');
  }
}
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var i=0;
    function createDiv()
    {


  if(i < 6) {
        var divTag = document.createElement("div");

        divTag.id = "div1";

        divTag.setAttribute("align","left");

        divTag.style.margin = "0px auto";

        divTag.className ="ex";

       divTag.innerHTML = "<img class='myimage' onclick='changeimage(this)' border='0' src='images/white_contact.png' width='60'/>";

        document.getElementById("newdiv").appendChild(divTag)

      }

   i++;
   $( ".ex" ).draggable({containment:'parent',cursor:'pointer',opacity:0.6});
 $( ".ex" ).droppable({ hoverClass:'border' });

    }





    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p align="left">
        <b>Click this button to create div element dynamically:</b>
        <input id="btn1" type="button" value="create div" onClick="createDiv();" />

        <div id = "newdiv">

</div>
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the fiddle to this ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events

Comment: Can I upload here instead